# Android Network Threading

Tags: java, android, multithreading, network-programming

I'm creating a network service that can send off multiple network calls at the same time. When giving the service an Executor to run on what would be the benefits of using the AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR vs a new Executor. Things to consider are the number of tasks that can be run at the same time vs memory and CPU consumption. I don't have to much experience with my own Executor's so I appreciate any explanations I can get. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Executor is an interface you implement. It's not very hard to, but AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR provides you with an Executor implementation to save you a little effort. AsyncTask is like that in general: it doesn't do any magic, it's just a convenience class for multithreading.

However, AsyncTask is designed to be called from the UI thread, and a "network service" should not be called from the UI thread, so you'll have to roll your own.

Comment: The problem with AsyncTasks is that they are difficult to manage.  You'll probably run them from the context of an Activity, and that is just so prone to error.  Build your own TPE, in a service, and manage it properly.